# Mockito: Intercept any methods that return a type

Tags: mockito

I've an interface like this:

```
public interface ICustomer extends IEnd<Customer> {
    String getId();
    ICustomer id(String id);
    ICustomer email(String email);
    ICustomer description(String description);
}
```

I need to mock any methods which returns an `ICustomer` regardless of parameters.

When these methods are called, the self called `ICustomer` have to be returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question?  If you have the three methods shown, then just mock your ICustomer interface and provide `when()` statements for each of the three methods.  Furthermore, I expect the implementations of your interface are fairly simple: looks like a POJO with a fluent API... are you sure you really need to mock the class anyway?  Only mock when you need to.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid to write an `when()` statement for each method. I thought I could to write something like `any method returns 'ICustomer' then returns me(proxy)`. Yes, it's a fluent api and it's intended to build a sentence with a remote payment gateway service. Sometimes, I need to the customer is not created on payment gateway... (for dev environments). Do you suggest me another approach?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need a custom Answer class:

```
public class CustomerAnswer implements Answer {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Class retType = invocation.getMethod().getReturnType();
        if (ICustomer.class.isInstance(retType)) {
            return invocation.getMock();
        }
        // provide default logic here -- override with "when()" calls.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then create your mock, specifying the default behavior:

```
Foo mockCustomer = mock(ICustomer.class, new CustomerAnswer());
```

Add, `when()` statements for other methods that need to be stubbed.

But as I commented in the OP, be sure you actually want to mock this class  before you go thru all the trouble.  Only mock when it will make the test code simpler.  If you have some simple implementation of the interface that is just a POJO with fluent API (no side-effects, no complicated dependencies or injections), there is probably no need to mock it.  Instead use a real instance, because the real instance already returns the original object.

If you need to `verify()` on the ICustomer object, then use a `@Spy` of a real instance of a ICustomer.